# What does 'module' object is not subscriptable mean?

Tags: python, module

Given time and distance (2000 points) from a CSV, I need to calculate velocity and acceleration:

```
import math

import numpy as np

import pandas as pd

#Excercise 2a

#input the csv

df = pd.read_csv('Data_oscillator.csv')

time = df['Time'].values

distance = df['x(t)'].values

velob = np.zeros(2000)

accelb = np.zeros(2000)

# differentiating distance to find new velocity and acceleration 

for i in range (0,1999):

    velob[i] = (distance[i+1] - distance[i])/(time[i+1] - time [i])

for i in range (0,1999):

    accelb[i] = (velob[i+1] - velob[i])/(time[i+1] - time[i])
```

I get the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-28-abd6ce780481> in <module>

      5 # differentiating distance to find new velocity and acceleration

      6 for i in range (0,1999):

----> 7     velob[i] = (distance[i+1] - distance[i])/(time[i+1] - time [i])

      8 

      9 for i in range (0,1999):


TypeError: 'module' object is not subscriptable
```

Answer (score 0):

The name of the variable `time` conflicts with a built-in Python library, which can be imported as a module (see [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html)). Applying the subscripts `[i]` to this is not allowed, hence the error message. Try changing the name of your variable to something other than `time`. In general, it is good practice to avoid generic variable names that may cause similar conflicts with modules; instead, favor more descriptive variable names:

```
import math

import numpy as np

import pandas as pd

#Excercise 2a

#input the csv

df = pd.read_csv('Data_oscillator.csv')

timeValues = df['Time'].values

distance = df['x(t)'].values

velob = np.zeros(2000)

accelb = np.zeros(2000)

# differentiating distance to find new velocity and acceleration 

for i in range (0,1999):

    velob[i] = (distance[i+1] - distance[i])/(timeValues[i+1] - timeValues[i])

for i in range (0,1999):

    accelb[i] = (velob[i+1] - velob[i])/(timeValues[i+1] - timeValues[i])
```